# jQuery: extract link-title text, put it in a new container and build an URL

Tags: jquery, url, text, attributes, extract

I have a gallery UL-list with some pictures. The `A-tags` (links) around images have some title-attributes with desription and a `"www.[...].com"` URL's.

Now a want to extract the whole `title-attribute` text and put it in a extra `SPAN-tag` right after the `A-tag` AND cerate an URL inside of this `SPAN-tag`.

here is my example:  [OLD vs. NEW](http://jsfiddle.net/p3SRK/1/)

---

What is the best and simplest way to do it with jQuery? I tried some plugins and librarys, but they are to large or do not exactly what I want. I just need a short function to do exactly one thing.

thank you

Comment: You asked a question and never come back check the answer?

Comment: sorry, just forgot about this project :) but yeah, your example did it! thank you

Comment: not a problem :) glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/p3SRK/2/)

```
$("#gallery1 a").each(function(index) {
   var arrTemp = $(this).attr("title").split(" // ");
   var Title = arrTemp[0];
   var Description = arrTemp[1];
   var URL = arrTemp[2];
   $(this).after( "<span>"+Title+"<br />"+Description+"<br /><a href='URL' target='_blank'>"+URL+"</a></span>" );
});
```

Comment: yeah, thanx, that's what I need! I just fixed the href-attribute here: http://jsfiddle.net/p3SRK/3/